# Firebase security: find other users via email

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Let's say we have these data in Firebase.

```
usersMail
    - "example1@mail.com": "1"
    - "example2@mail.com": "2"
    - "example3@mail.com": "3"
```

Is there anyway for user1 to query his own list of emails to look up his friends who are using the application without setting usersMail to be iterable by all users?

If this isn't possible in Firebase, would I have to set up a server with an admin account to do the querying? Still very new to the back-end stuff so I appreciate the help!

Comment: That Firebase structure probably isn't the best but what you are asking can certainly be done. It should really be  usersMail/-Yjo0ksip094koa/example1@mail.com: true,  /-Yp9490josokd9/example2@mail.com: true. That's makes a query easy or just observe the usersMail node for all of the emails (the -Yjo0... is created with childByAutoId to generate a 'random' key name). To secure the node, you would set up a Rule so only that user can read his own node. That being said, you may want to consider keeping a reference to the users instead of the actual email. That way, an email can be easily updated.

Comment: Sounds like an answer Jay. ;-)

Comment: @Jay Thanks, however I don't want a user to only be able to read his own node. E.g. user1 has user2's email on his phone, so the app should be able to ask if "example2@mail.com" exists in usersMail and obtain the UID for user2. I want it to be secured such that user3 cannot scrape all emails in usersMail if he wanted to. Is this possible?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen It's kinda an answer but I am not sure I understand the followup comment. Are you asking; a user already has another users email and you want to use that email to then lookup that user uid from a /users node? Yes, you can do that with a query but how did the user get the other users email in the first place? What's to prevent any user that 'has another users email' from querying for it. This may be a design issue in how the emails are initially obtained.

Comment: @Jay Yes that's exactly what I'm asking. In the scenario, user1 and user2 may be friends and I want them to be able to find each other. There's nothing to prevent user that 'has another users email' from querying. Thanks for taking your time :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the question is:  two users exist in Firebase, uid_0 and uid_1, and we need the ability for uid_0 to search for uid_1 by email.

However, we want to prevent other users from iterating over the users node.

The answer is no. This cannot be done. To query a users node for another user by email, a user would have to have access to each of the users within that node.

There may be another option however. Suppose uid_1 (doug) knows that uid_0 (bob) wants to find him and add him as a friend.

```
users
   uid_0:
     email: bob@greatwhitenorth.com
   uid_1:
     email: doug@greatwhitenorth.com
```

and then a node that links users together, in this case doug knows bob will be looking for him, we include doug's uid so when bob reads the node it will be included in the child data

```
email_finder
   doug@greatwhitenorth.com
        bob@greatwhitenorth.com: true
        uid: uid_1
```

and rules to limit access

```
rules for email_finder node
   $email
      read: root.child('email_finder').child($email)
                .child(
                       root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('email').val
                      )
                .val = true
```

If I typed that correctly,

```
root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('email').val
```

should retrieve the current users email from the users node, in this case bob@greatwhitenorth.com, so call that X

then

```
.child($email).child(X).val = true
```

to ensure that the email = true (exists) within the doug node

Then a direct observe would return the node containing the uid

```
let thisUserRef = emailFinderRef.childByAppendingValue("doug@greatwhitenorth.com")
thisUserRef.ObserveEventOfType(.Value...... {
 //capture the aid
}
```

You would also want a Rule on the users node that only allows a user to read their own node as well.

This is totally untested and possible even totally wrong but may give you a direction of a possible solution.