# Finding an UID by email in Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I first attempted to instantiate each user in the database like so:

```
emails : {
    email: "jerry@gmail.com" {
        uid: "x"
    }
}
```

I quickly found out that I can't store an email because it has an `@` and `.`. I was originally going to do an user look up like so:

```
func userLookUpByEmail (email: String) -> String {
    var userID: String = "nil"

    ref.queryOrderedByChild("emails").queryEqualToValue(email).observeSingleEventOfType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
            if snapshot.value != nil {
                print(snapshot.value)
                userID = snapshot.value as! String
            }
            else {
                print ("user not found")
                userID = "nil"
            }
    })
    return userID
}
```

However, I'm realizing that won't work. What is an effective way to receive an UID from providing an email?

Comment: Your data structure is not valid JSON. Please update your question with valid JSON.

Comment: Something like this seems the simplest data structure to do what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37897656/firebase-security-find-other-users-via-email/37909700#37909700

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering your question, since you can't have the email as the child key you can **do the other way, setting the uid as the key and the email as the child**.

```
emails : {
    uid: {
        email: "jerry@gmail.com"
    }
}
```

And then your code will change a little bit.

```
func userLookUpByEmail (email: String, completionHandler: (result: String) -> Void) {
    var userID: String = "nil"
    ref.child("emails").queryOrderedByChild("email").queryEqualToValue(email).observeSingleEventOfType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
                if snapshot.value != nil {
                    print(snapshot.key)
                    userID = snapshot.key as! String
                }
                else {
                    print ("user not found")
                    userID = "nil"
                }
                completionHandler(userID)
        })
 }
```

Calling `userLookUpByEmail`:

```
userLookUpByEmail(email) {
    (result: String) in
    print("\(result)")
}
```

On the other hand I'm wondering why do you have an `emails` branch in your database since you could have an `users` branch (if you don't have yet) and store any user data there, including the email. This would make your data structure much more clean and reliable. Again, I'm wondering here since I don't exactly know your needs.

```
users : {
    uid: {
        email: "jerry@gmail.com",
        name: "Jerry Maguire",
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I get the error `Using an unspecified index. Consider adding ".indexOn": "email" at /emails to your security rules for better performance`. Should my rules look like `{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
    "/emails" {
      ".indexOn" : "email"
    }
  }
}` ?

Comment: @user5812721 This is not an error. Your code should work without it since its just for internal firebase performance. The rules you are looking for is: `{ "rules": { ".read": "auth != null", ".write": "auth != null", "emails": { ".indexOn" : "email" } } }`

Comment: Before I added the rules the snapshot key would be found, but now it's always nil. Also after my `})` I wrote `print(userid)` but it came up nil too, thats why I thought it was an error. Before I added the rules, I printed the snapshot key inside the first if statement and it was always correct.

Comment: @user5812721 are you authenticated? Also, if you try to print the userID after the `})` it will fail since you are calling it out of the assync callback function. If you want to print it print before the return statement that you can find in my code.

Comment: Oh, `userLookUpByEmail` always returns whatever I initialized userid to be. How do I change that?

Comment: I can't return before the `})` because `unexpected non void return value in void function`

Comment: Nevermind, i fully read the other answer and now see what I overlooked

Comment: @user5812721 My bad, you wont be able to return at all. You should work with [completionHandler](https://thatthinginswift.com/completion-handlers/) in this case. I've edited the question with the proper information. Anyway, nice that you did it. :)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you are correct that you cannot store certain characters in the database. According to the Firebase docs, (https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data)

> If you create your own keys, they must be UTF-8 encoded, can be a maximum of 768 bytes, and cannot contain ., $, #, [, ], /, or ASCII control characters 0-31 or 127.

As you can see, however, the "@" symbol is not one of them. As for the dot, you can have a function that replaces the dot with another character. For example, "•". Here is an example:

```
func createNewEmail(oldEmail: String) -> String{
    return oldEmail.componentsSeparatedByString(".").joinWithSeparator("•")
}
```

What that does is it splits the email into an array of "email@example" and "com". Then, it re-joins them with the new character, creating "email@example•com"

If you ever needed the old email, you could just do the same thing in reverse.

```
func getOldEmail(newEmail: String) -> String{
    return newEmail.componentsSeparatedByString("•").joinWithSeparator(".")
}
```

You could then format your tree like this

```
emails:
    email@example•com: UID123456789
```

Finally, for your original question, the function could be written like this

```
func userLookUpByEmail (email: String) -> String {
    let newEmail = createNewEmail(email)
    var userID: String = "nil"

    ref.child("emails").child(newEmail).observeSingleEventOfType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
            if snapshot.value != nil {
                print(snapshot.value)
                userID = snapshot.value as! String
            }
            else {
                print ("user not found")
                userID = "nil"
            }
    })
    return userID
}
```

However, it is possible that you will get "nil" every time. This is because observeSingleEventOfType is a closure. This means that it runs in the background of your app. Because of this, userID might be returned before it gets changed inside the closure. Instead of returning userID, you might want to run any code based on userID inside of the closure. For example, instead of doing this:

```
func userLookUpByEmail (email: String) -> String {
    let newEmail = createNewEmail(email)
    var userID: String = "nil"

    ref.child("emails").child(newEmail).observeSingleEventOfType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
            if snapshot.value != nil {
                print(snapshot.value)
                userID = snapshot.value as! String
            }
            else {
                print ("user not found")
                userID = "nil"
            }
    })
    return userID
}

doSomethingWith(lookUserUpByEmail(email@example.com))
```

You could do this:

```
func userLookUpByEmail (email: String){
    let newEmail = createNewEmail(email)
    var userID: String = "nil"

    ref.child("emails").child(newEmail).observeSingleEventOfType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
            if snapshot.value != nil {
                print(snapshot.value)
                userID = snapshot.value as! String
                doSomethingWith(userID)
            }
            else {
                print ("user not found")
                userID = "nil"
                doSomethingWith(userID)
            }
    })
}
```

Comment: I saved it to a class's var called `temp_uid` then saved that variable into `user2uid` after I had called `userLookUpByEmail`, yet the `temp_uid` still doesn't receive the correct value in time.

Comment: @user5812721 You basically can't put anything outside of the closure. For the most part, anything you put outside the brackets won't work properly. Trying to beat the clock doesn't work. You need to put _everything_ that you want to do with `snapshot` inside the closure. If you want do something with those values, make a function, and then place it inside. For example, where I put `doSomethingWith(userID)`, you can put whatever you want.

Comment: To clarify... You can store data outside the closure/block but you should not act on that data until the snapshot is valid inside the block. So for example you can have a class level array self.myArray (a tableview datasource) outside the block. You would fill that array from the snapshot inside the block and would also tell your tableview to reload itself from inside the block, after the array was populated, again inside the block.